# make javascript literal inheriting from different prototype

Tags: javascript, eval, literals

I have a some code that probably goes against what is good practice. However, this is not what I want comments on - this is purely academic.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function run() {
    var fakeContext = {
         Array : fr.contentWindow.Array || fr.Array; //Another context/window array
    }

    fakeContext.Array.prototype.remove = function(el) {/*some code*/};

    with (fakeContext) {
        var someCode = "var x = ['1', '2']; x.remove('2')"; 
        eval(someCode);
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="about:blank" name="fr"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

This array created when evaluating someCode inherits from the top level Array in which the code runs instead of inheriting from the `fakeContext.Array`. Meaning the array x does not have the prototype function `.remove()`

How can I (if there is a way) get the literals in the `someCode`-string to inherit from the `fakeContext`s `Array.prototype`?

Comment: First of all, you have several syntax errors. On the 2nd line: you can't assign inside object literal; on the 7th line: should be `with`, keywords in JS are case-sensitive.

Comment: This looks like it should work. Platform issue maybe?

Comment: What are your trying to do? Why do you need a "fake" Array class?

Comment: I have the code in order to further explain the problem.

I am trying to run some code in another context. Everything works fine except prototyping on literals such as Number, Boolean, String, Array, etc.

Comment: I suspect you are trying to create a new context faking the global one to execute "safely" `eval`. But it won't work in that way.

Comment: @PabloLozano You are correct in that assumption. I know it wont work in the way i am doing it. I am looking for a way to do it so prototype inheritance will work on literals as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that an Array literal `[]` does not evaluate in the same way as `new Array()`. The first will just create a native `Array` object, while the second checks the scope for a `Array` variable and executes it as a constructor.

```
var fakeWin = fr.contentWindow || fr;
var fakeContext = {Array: fakeWin.Array};

with (fakeContext) {
    Array.prototype.remove = function(el) {/*some code*/};
    eval("var x = new Array('1', '2'); x.remove('2')");
}
```

To create Arrays with a prototype from a different context, you will need to `eval` the literals *in* the fake window environment:

```
var fakeWin = fr.contentWindow || fr;

with (fakeWin) {
    Array.prototype.remove = function(el) {/*some code*/};
    eval("var x = new Array('1', '2'); x.remove('2')");
}

// or:

fakeWin.Array.prototype.remove = function(el) {/*some code*/};
fakeWin.eval("var x = new Array('1', '2'); x.remove('2')");
```

Comment: Thanks. This will work for my case, however, we are evalling some rather large scripts once in a while an that takes some time replacing  all literals in a script.

Comment: I didn't say you would need to replace them. But you anyway said the question was purely academic? For production, you should consider a better approach.